# dmenu alternative for windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, launcher

I really like using [dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/) on *nix systems: are there any alternatives for windows?

I've tried [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), but it is slow and I don't like its interface.

Comment: related to http://superuser.com/questions/63436/spotlight-equivalent-for-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/launchy/?profile=windows&platform=windows) are a list of alternatives to Launchy. I recommend you try Enso and Slickrun. Executor looks pretty cool as well haven't tried that one yet.

You can get a new skin for Launchy if you don't like the look and if you want it to be faster I suggest you make you Caps Lock key execute Scroll Lock and set Launchy to open on Scroll Lock

[Launchy Skins](http://www.launchy.net/skins.php)

Registry Code to Swap Keys

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,46,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00`